# Creating queue of element with GCD

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, queue, grand-central-dispatch

I have downloaded images and saved it to a GCD, updated the count of images and performed a post notification in queue. What is happening now is that it does not register that I have downloaded the images.  Sometimes I am missing some images, and I think it is because I have missed something in my GCD logic.

Here is my code:

```
for (NSString *i in items)
{
[[RequestAPI sharedInstance]downloadImage:i completion:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, UIImage *image, NSError *error) {

 //1. here main thread I receive images and go to BG

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

   //2. here I save image on disk and get path
        NSString *path = [ImageManager saveImageToDisk:image toEntity:entity withparams:@{@"save" : @"lala"}];
      __block  NSMutableDictionary *attachments = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
      __block  NSMutableArray *photoPaths = [NSMutableArray array];



      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

       //3. here I load entity and dictionary from it with NSKeyedUnarchiver from CD and set to it image path
        if (entity.attachments)
        {
            attachments = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:entity.attachments];
            if (attachments[type])
            {
                photoPaths = attachments[type];
            }
        }

          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

          //4. here I check all images equality ti themselves  in entity   
        BOOL haveDublicate = NO;
        NSData *i = [ImageManager imageDataFromPath:path];
        NSArray *photoImages = [ImageManager imageDatasFromPaths:photoPaths];
        for (NSData *saved in photoImages)
        {
            if ([saved isEqualToData: i])

            {
                haveDublicate = YES;
            }
        }

        if (!photoPaths)
        {
            photoPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
        }



               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

               //5. and finally if all ok I save image path, change load counter and post notification
                         if (path.length
            && ![photoPaths containsObject:path]
            && !haveDublicate
            )
        {
            [photoPaths addObject:path];
            [savedLinks setObject:photoPaths forKey:type];

            entity.attachments = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:savedLinks];

            [self saveContext];
        }
        [RequestAPI sharedInstance].downloadsCount -= 1;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:kReloadFeedData object:nil];



               });
           });
       });
    });
}];
```

I think here I need process 1-2-3-4-5 to get desired result. Am I right or how can I do this queuing?

Comment: I can't figure out your description of what you ware doing. Post entire methods.

Comment: The first block of code you posted shows 4 nested block invocations, and NO CODE. Post your ACTUAL CODE.

Comment: yep, now, I make complete update

Comment: Your code is a mess. Why in the world do you have 4 nested block invocations? Why are you creating an empty mutable dictionary and an empty mutable array, only to discard them a few lines later and replace them with immutable objects from your keyed archiver? How do the results of your download get installed into "entity.attachments". I see problems with almost every line of your code. It's pretty clear you are in over your head.

Comment: have 4 nested block invocations -- because block saveImageToDisk and block that finds duplicates are slow, I run it in BG and they are in middle of other actions

Comment: I have  a lot of problems with work of this part of app, this works but not clear and I lost some downloaded images, I do not know how to write this case better...